# How do I get Xcode to read UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift

I've just started learning code and app development, I've been building a golf scorecard app as my first project as I want an app that ill use myself I have a basic layout with UITextFields for each score and a label at the end for the total, now I want to make the label automatically calculate and display the total based on the input data collected but I'm going wrong somewhere. here is the code I've written so far could someone explain where I've gone wrong please? Please keep in mind I'm self-taught and only been coding for a few weeks!
using the latest version of Xcode and the swift UI 
thanks in advance, Joel

```swift
@IBOutlet var p1h1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var p1h2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var p1t1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!

@IBAction func p1t1(_ sender: Int) {
  func holedata() {
    let h1 = p1h1.text
    let h2 = p1h2.text

    func add(h1: Int, h2: Int) -> Int {
      let sum = h1 + h2
      p1t1.text = String(sum)
      return (sum)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m not receiving errors but the total doesn’t display as the answer to the sum I believe it’s not reading the data for the scores I put in

Answer (score 0):

Change the textfield text to Int and add the two.

Replace :

```
  let h1 = p1h1.text
  let h2 = p1h2.text
```

With :

```
 let h1 = Int(p1h1.text)
 let h2 = Int(p1h2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a function in another function. Your `func p1t1` just assigns two variables and doesn't call add() func. You should paste func add() on the same level as p1t1 and call it inside p1t1. And yes, you should cast String values to Int as it was mentioned in previous answer.

BTW it is very bad practice to name your variables in such way.

```
@IBAction func p1t1(_ sender: Int) {
  func holedata() {
    let h1 = Int(p1h1.text)
    let h2 = Int(p1h2.text)

    add(h1: h1, h2: h2)
  }
}

func add(h1: Int, h2: Int) -> Int {
      let sum = h1 + h2
      p1t1.text = String(sum)
      return (sum)
  }
```